# Use XLSX Node Module in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5

I am currently building an application that should export an XLSX file (but not table data, I have some data that I want to put into an XLSX in a specific way). Since I couldn't find any way to do it with SAPUI5 standard components (sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet does not work for me, since it would need table like data) I was thinking about including the  [nodeJS XLSX Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx). To do that I tried to follow the following tutorial: [Using NPM Packages in UI5 without Shims](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-blogs-by-sap/using-npm-packages-in-ui5-without-shims/ba-p/13498798), but after doing the first few steps I realized that this is just working for custom components.

Has anyone an idea how to realize that in a different way?